Mechanical mechanism to store and update state of fixed state transition table
Given a state transition table like this:
1->3
2->1
3->4
4->2

(If the system is in state 1, next change to state 3 etc.)
In my actual use case there are 15 states/transitions, and multiple states may lead to the same state, and a state may lead to itself. Reordering of the states to reduce complexity is possible, but they won't generally behave as nicely as in this simple example which forms a closed loop.
How could one implement this purely mechanically? This kind of discrete change from one state to the next?
So far I can imagine two ways:
Using a wheel, where a specific angle/rotation segment represents a state, cut grooves into its side, from the center to the edge of the wheel where the segment of the next state is
(a face cam, somewhat similar to this mechanism).

and then have a follower move from the center along the groove to the edge, turning it to another angle, stopping the wheel when it has exited the edge. Once it has left the groove, the rod which holds the follower moves away from the wheel, back to its center and then moves from the center into the next groove again (this could be acomplished with a Chebyshev lambda linkage for example).

A potential problem with this mechanism is that the grooves will probably intersect, making it unreliable due to jamming (which may be mitigated by having a bean shaped follower like this, which would cause it to follow its current groove even if another intersected at an angle). It may also be possible to distribute grooves among multiple wheels.
Another idea may be to use a row of mechanical 1-bit registers, where each represents a state and is connected to the input of one other register - the next state from this one. Only one register would be active at a time and after setting another one to active/"1", it would set itself to "0" (unless setting/transitioning to itself). But I'm not sure how to implement this specifically mechanically.
My goal is to construct a purely mechanical Universal Turing Machine, which at their core use such state transition tables to compute arbitrary programs. These update their state not only depending on the current state, but also on another input which takes one of multiple values. But this could be achieved by, say, selecting one of multiple wheels which are connected and turning together, one for each set of transitions for a given input. Or grooves in two sides of the same wheel. With the 1-bit register approach, having two activation lines from each one, one for each input, and only selectively activating one.

Perhaps what you want is something like a railroad interlocking system, which is a mechanical state machine that can be driven forward/backward through a sequence of states, but only "legal" transitions are allowed from any given state. Otherwise, I'm not really sure what your end goal is -- can you be more specific in your question?

Call the states ABCD, where A is 1, B is 3, C is 4, D is 2. And so strangeness to the order. So why not just make these states be ordered on a wheel in the natural state transition of the wheel? All you need are detents to mark the states and you're all set.

@Abel While this would work for this simplified example, and reordering is generally a good idea, this won't work in my actual use case with 15 (seemingly) quite randomly connected states

@DaveTweed Thank you, interesting! I added a description of what I want to achieve

It's just as easy to have states be complex via a binary approach. Just have 15 wheels tied to the same shaft where something being in the detent dictates presence in that state. Music box. You can have multiple states active but as that is not your intent, just don't have any of the detents line up at the same angle.

@Abel I guess it is possible to decompose a state transition table into components/subgraphs that loop or end in some state, hmm

Create a mechanical nand gate. From that you can synthesize ANY logical circuit.

@GregLocock that will result in a mechanism with many (unreliable) parts however
